# Export complete datatable at once into text file

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `datatable` and exporting row wise data to text file

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Tables[0].Rows)
{                
    WriteToFile("Docket with Docket number {0} and Request ID {1}   booked from Agent Account having Login ID {2} on {3}"+ dr["DOCKET_NUMBER"].ToString()+
       dr["REQUEST_ID"].ToString()+ dr["CREATED_BY"].ToString()+dr["CREATE_DATE"].ToString());
}

 private static void WriteToFile(string text)
{
        string path = "E:\\ServiceLog.txt";
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")+ "      "+ text));
           // writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text +));
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

can i export whole `datatable` to text file at once??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class and its methods i.e. [`AppendFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`AppendLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257(v=vs.110).aspx) to read all rows. then afterwards just invoke you method  `WriteToFile`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Tables[0].Rows)
{                
    sb.AppendFormat("Docket with Docket number {0} and Request ID {1}   booked from Agent Account having Login ID {2} on {3}", dr["DOCKET_NUMBER"].ToString(), dr["REQUEST_ID"].ToString(), dr["CREATED_BY"].ToString(), dr["CREATE_DATE"].ToString());
    sb.AppendLine();
}
WriteToFile(sb);
```

Comment: but the purpose is to avoid looping through each row and save time, and with StringBuilder still we are doing the same..

Comment: @Soniya, But you are writing to file only once, and to read all rows you have to iterate either using simple `for` loop or LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this..

```
var lines = dt1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dr => "Docket with Docket number {0} and Request ID {1}   booked from Agent Account having Login ID {2} on {3}" + dr["DOCKET_NUMBER"].ToString() +
       dr["REQUEST_ID"].ToString() + dr["CREATED_BY"].ToString() + dr["CREATE_DATE"].ToString());
File.WriteAllLines("YourFilePath",lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about writing to xml? Xml is a text, so the condition is met.

Use [DataTable.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx) method for writing and [DataTable.ReadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx) method for reading data to/from text file.

Answer (score 0):

i've never write Datatable into txt file, but i would suggest you to try ClosedXml and write Datatable into csv file at once. 
ClosedXml is one great library and i've no problem running it on production so far, you should check out their [github](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) page on how to use it and or extend it.